# How to set Wooommerce default featured category images as product featured imaged based on category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Im after some help, I want to be able to replace all my product featured images with the default product category image that I have set.

I have found a plug in that does the reverse however Im not sure what changes will need to be made to reverse it?

Would anyone be able to help?

The original plugin author said the below when I asked

'That should be possible, although I'm not aware of any links off the top of my head. A function called "woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail" is hooked in the "woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title" action that you could remove and replace, similar to how my plugin works. The function essentially just calls the "woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail" function found [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail.html#924-938) which looks simple enough to muck about with!'

```
namespace GazChap;
```

class WC_Category_Product_Thumbnails {

```
private $shuffle = true;
private $recurse_category_ids = true;
private $limit = 20; // number of most recent products to fetch when shuffle is true, lower means faster

/**
 * WC_Category_Product_Thumbnails constructor.
 * Sets a default limit (to -1, i.e. all posts) if none already set and then replaces WC actions with ours
 */
public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'replace_wc_actions' ) );

    if ( !$this->limit ) $this->limit = -1;
}

/**
 * Removes the action that puts the thumbnail before the subcategory title, and replaces it with our version
 */
public function replace_wc_actions() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', array( $this, 'auto_subcategory_thumbnail' ) );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sections_products', array( $this, 'add_setting_section' ) );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_products', array( $this, 'add_settings_to_section' ), 10, 2 );
}

/**
 * The function that does all the donkey work.
 * @param \WP_Term $category - the category that we're dealing with
 */
public function auto_subcategory_thumbnail( $category ) {

    // does this category already have a thumbnail defined? if so, use that instead
    if ( get_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ) ) {
        woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail( $category );
        return;
    }

    // get a list of category IDs inside this category (so we're fetching products from all subcategories, not just the top level one)
    if ( $this->recurse_category_ids ) {
        $category_ids = $this->get_sub_category_ids( $category );
    } else {
        $category_ids = array( $category->term_id );
    }

    $query_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $this->shuffle ? $this->limit : 1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                'value' => '',
                'compare' => '!=',
            ),
        ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $category_ids,
                'operator' => 'IN',
            ),
        ),
    );

    $products = get_posts( $query_args );
    if ( $products ) {
        $image_size = 'shop_thumbnail';
        if ( get_option('gazchap-wc-category-product-thumbnails_category-size') ) {
            $image_size = get_option('gazchap-wc-category-product-thumbnails_category-size');
        }
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $products[ array_rand( $products ) ]->ID, $image_size );
    } else {
        // show the default placeholder category image if there's no products inside this one
        woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail( $category );
    }
}

/**
 * Recursive function to fetch a list of child category IDs for the one passed
 *
 * @param \WP_Term $start - the category to start from
 * @param array $results - this just stores the results as they're being built up
 *
 * @return array - an array of term IDs for each product_cat inside the original one
 */
private function get_sub_category_ids( $start, $results = array() ) {
    if ( !is_array( $results ) ) $results = array();

    $results[] = $start->term_id;
    $cats = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $start->term_id ) );
    if ( is_array( $cats ) ) {
        foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
            $results = $this->get_sub_category_ids( $cat, $results );
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

function add_setting_section( $sections ) {

    $sections['gazchap-wc-category-thumbnails'] = __( 'Auto Category Thumbnails', 'gazchap-wc-category-product-thumbnails' );
    return $sections;

}

function add_settings_to_section( $settings, $current_section ) {
    /**
     * Check the current section is what we want
     **/
    if ( $current_section == 'gazchap-wc-category-thumbnails' ) {
        $new_settings = array();
        // Add Title to the Settings
        $new_settings[] = array( 'name' => __( 'Auto Category Thumbnails Settings', 'gazchap-wc-category-product-thumbnails' ), 'type' => 'title', 'desc' => __( 'The following options are used to configure GazChap\'s Auto Category Thumbnails', 'text-domain' ), 'id' => 'gazchap-wc-category-thumbnails' );

        $temp = $this->_get_all_image_sizes();
        $image_sizes = array();
        foreach( $temp as $image_size => $image_spec_array ) {
            $image_spec = "";
            $image_spec .= ($image_spec_array['width'] > 0) ? $image_spec_array['width'] : 'auto';
            $image_spec .= ' x ';
            $image_spec .= ($image_spec_array['height'] > 0) ? $image_spec_array['height'] : 'auto';
            if ( $image_spec_array['crop'] ) {
                $image_spec .= ", cropped";
            }
            $image_sizes[ $image_size ] = $image_size . " (" . $image_spec . ")";
        }

        // Add first checkbox option
        $new_settings[] = array(
            'name'     => __( 'Thumbnail Size', 'text-domain' ),
            'desc_tip' => __( 'Choose the image size to use for the thumbnails', 'gazchap-wc-category-thumbnails' ),
            'id'       => 'gazchap-wc-category-product-thumbnails_category-size',
            'type'     => 'select',
            'options' => $image_sizes,
            'desc'     => __( 'Choose the image size to use for the thumbnails', 'gazchap-wc-category-thumbnails' ),
        );

        $new_settings[] = array( 'type' => 'sectionend', 'id' => 'gazchap-wc-category-thumbnails' );
        return $new_settings;

    /**
     * If not, return the standard settings
     **/
    } else {
        return $settings;
    }
}

private function _get_all_image_sizes() {
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    $default_image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

    foreach ( $default_image_sizes as $size ) {
        $image_sizes[ $size ][ 'width' ] = intval( get_option( "{$size}_size_w" ) );
        $image_sizes[ $size ][ 'height' ] = intval( get_option( "{$size}_size_h" ) );
        $image_sizes[ $size ][ 'crop' ] = get_option( "{$size}_crop" ) ? get_option( "{$size}_crop" ) : false;
    }

    if ( isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) && count( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) ) {
        $image_sizes = array_merge( $image_sizes, $_wp_additional_image_sizes );
    }

    return $image_sizes;
}
```

}

new WC_Category_Product_Thumbnails();

If anyone can help it would be most appreciated or be able to provide another way how to achieve this!

Comment: This is another opposite example of what im trying to achieve : https://gist.github.com/ashfame/9629652